# Pass a Nokogiri::XML::Element into Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, delayed-job

I create a variable, called `node`:

```
doc.xpath('//Product').each do |node|
```

and pass it into a delayed job like this:

```
delay.create_new_book_record(client_id, user_id, node)
```

and although the variable 'node' I'm passing in looks something like this just before I pass it into the delayed method:

```
  //node.inspect #=> 
  <Product>
   <RecordReference>9780857380272</RecordReference>
   <NotificationType>02</NotificationType>
   #...etc
```

it is passed in like this to delayed job which looks like an empty hash to me:

```
INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs"
....
:create_new_book_record\nargs:\n- 1\n- 2\n- !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Element {}\n"]
```

And the error that gets thrown when I try to parse node in the delayed_job task is

```
wrong argument type Nokogiri::XML::Element (expected Data)
```

So: how do I pass a Nokogiri::XML::Element into a delayed job task so that it can be processed within the task?

Answer (score 1):

nvm: you can simplify what you pass as arguments and re-build a nokogiri object at the other end:

```
client_id = 1
user_id   = 2
node_to_s = node.to_s
book      = Book.where(:blah => blah)
delay.update_book_record(client_id, user_id, book.first.id, node_to_s)


def update_book_record(c, u, b, n)
  book = Book.find(b)
  node = Nokogiri::XML(n)
  #...
```